# Two parameters in like query Hibernate Query

Tags: hibernate, hql, spring-data-jpa

I have one field named 'uniqueCode' which formed using city and salesPersonId and some count.
**format:** uniqueCode = City + SalesPersonId + 101
**example:**    AHM1101=AHM+1+101
Now, I want a method which would take city and salespersonId and return me max of uniqueId.
I have written query like this:

```
@Query("SELECT max(s.uniqueCode) FROM ServiceProvider s WHERE s.uniqueCode LIKE :cityCode:salesPersonId%")
public String maxUniqueCode(@Param("cityCode") String cityCode, @Param("salesPersonId") Long salesPersonId);
```

But it is giving error that **Unexpected token: salesPersonId** .
What is the correct way to write this query.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to join your params into single string using `CONCAT(:cityCode, :salesPersonId, '%')` and it should work:

```
@Query("SELECT max(s.uniqueCode) FROM ServiceProvider s WHERE s.uniqueCode LIKE CONCAT(:cityCode, :salesPersonId, '%')")
public String maxUniqueCode(@Param("cityCode") String cityCode, @Param("salesPersonId") Long salesPersonId);
```

Comment: Thanks man, i just needed to google for concatenating parameters. I just found that, other way we can achieve it is by using `||` operator.

Comment: @RajKantaria Yes you can use that. However I think that `||` is Hibernate specific, whereas `CONCAT` is defined by JPA standard. So by using `CONCAT` your query should be compatible if you switch from Hibernate JPA provider to something else (probably unlikely, but worth mentioning nonetheless).

Answer (score 0):

The like operand is expecting a string value with apostrophes around it. 
For example, if you are looking for the AHM1%, the correct way to write this query would be - 
SELECT max(s.uniqueCode) FROM ServiceProvider s WHERE s.uniqueCode LIKE 'AHM1%'

Try adding those around your search string and see if it helps.